# Layout cannot be read using actionbarsherlock version 4.4.0

Tags: java, android

i try to use actionbarsherlock, when i use actionbarsherlock version 4.4.0 layout in my project cannot be read from my class. I had try to delete apppcompat_v7, but always fail.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kodim"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.kodim.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kodim.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.class

```
package com.example.kodim;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;




    public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }



    }
```

I want to write this code `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`  , but the `activity_main` cannot be read from my class. Can you give me solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are importing `android.R` instead of your package name resource class.

Replace `import android.R;` with `import com.example.kodim.R;`.

Comment: Thanks brow...  i'm new at sherlockactionbar. It works @J.Romero